# justify content center property in bootstrap not working to center contents in a row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, alignment, row

i have created a section in bootstrap, the section contains 8 buttons, 5 in the first row and 3 in the second, now when i created the section, it looks something like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RbLf.png)

which is not how i want to align the contents, i want to align the contents like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIwI9.png)

for this i added justify content and also mx-auto property to my row, but nothing works, my complete code is below:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .banner-cta {
    background: #23746F;
    padding: 30px;
  }
  
  .banner-cta h2,
  .banner-cta p,
  .banner-cta a {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
  }
  
  .banner-cta h2,
  .banner-cta p {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
  
  .banner-cta p {
    max-width: 700px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
  
  #dada {
    padding-bottom: 1%;
  }
</style>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="banner-cta">
    <h2 class="banner-cta-title">PARTY AT RAMOJI FILM CITY</h2>
    <div id="dada" class="row justify-content-center">
      <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-light btn-md">DAY TOURISM</button></a>
      <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-light btn-md">BIRTHDAY PARTY</button></a>
      <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-light btn-md">SAHAS</button></a>
      <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-light btn-md">CORPORATE PACKAGES</button></a>
      <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-light btn-md">VENUE BOOKINGS</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-light btn-md">SURPRISE PARTY</button></a>
      <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-light btn-md">POST WEDDING RELAX</button></a>
      <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-light btn-md">WEDDING STYLE</button></a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

can anyone please tell me what is wrong in my code, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.banner-cta a {
    margin: auto;
  }
```

No need there.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .banner-cta {
    background: #23746F;
    padding: 30px;
  }
  
  .banner-cta h2,
  .banner-cta p,
  .banner-cta a {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    margin:2px; //or more if you need
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif !important;
  }
  
  .banner-cta h2,
  .banner-cta p {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
  }
  
  .banner-cta p {
    max-width: 700px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
  }
  
  #dada {
    padding-bottom: 1%;
  }
  .row{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center
  }
</style>


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="banner-cta">
    <h2 class="banner-cta-title">PARTY AT RAMOJI FILM CITY</h2>
    <div id="dada" class="row justify-content-center">
      <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-light btn-md">DAY TOURISM</button></a>
      <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-light btn-md">BIRTHDAY PARTY</button></a>
      <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-light btn-md">SAHAS</button></a>
      <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-light btn-md">CORPORATE PACKAGES</button></a>
      <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-light btn-md">VENUE BOOKINGS</button></a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-light btn-md">SURPRISE PARTY</button></a>
      <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-light btn-md">POST WEDDING RELAX</button></a>
      <a href="#"><button class="btn btn-light btn-md">WEDDING STYLE</button></a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, i had one more doubt, how can i remove the white space from left and right of the section?

Comment: add "p-0" class to div with container-fluid class to remove white space.